# Why conditional type with any works differently?

Tags: typescript

The question is pretty simple, why in this situation `type s` is a union of both variables.

```
type s = any extends boolean ? 'Yes' : 'no';
```

It seems logical that any type can literally be anything but is there a better explanation of this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could give my *opinion* for why this is the case, but that's not really what you're asking for, I gather.

The only *canonical* explanation for why this behavior happens that I can find is from the comment in lines #13287 through #13290 of [`checker.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.9.6/src/compiler/checker.ts#L13287-L13290) where it's implemented (you can't directly view files that large on GitHub ‍♂️):

```
// Return union of trueType and falseType for 'any' since it matches anything
if (checkType.flags & TypeFlags.Any) {
  (extraTypes || (extraTypes = [])).push(
    instantiateTypeWithoutDepthIncrease(root.trueType, combinedMapper || mapper)
  );
}
```

All other references I can find to this behavior just confirm that it *is* that way, not *why*.  For example, [microsoft/TypeScript#27418](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27418) asks what conditional types where the checked type is `unknown` should evaluate to, and mentions: "to add to the confusion, `any` also has its own wildcard behavior that matches both branches".  In this case, `unknown extends X ? T : F` will only return `T` if `X` is `unknown`, and `F` otherwise; it never returns `T | F`.

So the closest to an authoritative answer I can see here is because the implementer said "`any` matches anything, so return the union of both branches".  Oh well, hope that helps; good luck!