# why "any" type extends another type will always be union type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

example:

```
type A = any extends 1 ? 2 : 3 // result: type A = 2 | 3
```

Just curiously, why `A` is `2|3` rather than `2`?

I think it is because `Distributive` feature and `any` means any type's union, so it is equivalent to:

```
type A = 0 | 1 | ... extends 1 ? 2 : 3 // => (0 extends 1 ? 2 : 3) | (1 extends 1 ? 2 : 3) | ...
```

But I can't sure it. Does someone has better explanation or official explanation that can explain it?

Comment: duplicate: [Why conditional type with any works differently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62881243/why-conditional-type-with-any-works-differently)